# Chain multiple function return values using AND in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am having trouble getting a bash if statement to only execute if three functions all return zero. I made a simple example and could not get the if statement at the bottom to run (the else portion of the code runs). Am I setting up the if statement wrong?

```
test() {
  NUM=3
  BUM=4
  if [ $(NUM) -lt $(BUM) ];
  then 
    return 0;
  else
    return 1;
  fi;
}

test2() {
  NUM=4
  BUM=5
  if [ $(NUM) -lt $(BUM) ];
  then 
    return 0;
  else
    return 1;
  fi;
}

test3() {
  NUM=13
  BUM=133
  if [ $(NUM) -lt $(BUM) ];
  then 
    return 0;
  else
    return 1;
  fi;
}

if [[ ${test} && ${test2} && ${test3} ]]; then 
  echo "successfully chained function values"
else
  echo "ands did not chain successfully"
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `[[` , it tests conditions but doesn't run anything. Use the functions directly:

```
if test && test2 && test3 ; then
    echo Success
fi
```